# Downloading kotlin-stdlib and kotest runner taking almost infinity time

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

In my android project when I hit the sync button downloading kotlin-sdklib and kotest-runner-junit taking very long time.

[image: Example how downloading process is going]

It took 16 minutes. And this is going every time when gradle changes. Other projects working fine, problem only with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I've added

```
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/terrakok/terramaven" }
```

in my project `build.gradle` `allprojects -> repositories`. I've removed it and added `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()` instead.

before:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/terrakok/terramaven" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

after:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```